# Scoping input in rshiny not found

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

A sequence cannot be generated because `input$amount` is not generating, possibly due to my folder structure.

Error Message:
[image]

Consider an rshiny app with the following folder structure:

```
.
├── app.R
├── _ui_elements
|   ├── body.R
|   ├── sidebar.R
|   └── _tabs
|       └── example_tab.R
```

Wherein the code is as follows:

```
app.R
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)

source("ui_elements/sidebar.R", local = TRUE)
source("ui_elements/body.R", local = TRUE)

ui <-
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
    sidebar,
    body
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  amount_df <- reactive({
     tibble(amount = seq(1, input$amount))
  })

  output$amount_curve <- renderPlotly({

    amount_df() %>%
      ggplot(aes(amount)) +
        geom_point()

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

body.R
source("ui_elements/tabs/tab_example.R", local = TRUE)

body <-
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tab_example
      )
    )

sidebar.R
sidebar <-
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Example", tabName = "example", icon = icon("couch"))
      )
    )

tab_example.R
tab_example <-
tabItem(tabName = "example",
        fluidRow(
          column(6, numericInput("Amount","amount", min = 1, max = 1000, value = 500)),
          column(6, plotlyOutput("amount_curve"))
          )
        )
```

Comment: `amount_df <- reactive({
     req(input$amount)
     tibble(amount = seq(1, input$amount))
  })`

Comment: @PorkChop This doesn't work (no error message, but nothing renders), and shouldn't be necessary, `input$amount` has a declared value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the file structure but the passing of parameters. You have the wrong order of the parameters `inputId` and `label`. Change the code in `tab_example.R` to the following.

```
tab_example <-
  tabItem(tabName = "example",
          fluidRow(
            column(6, numericInput(inputId = "amount",label = "Amount", min = 1, max = 1000, value = 500)),
            column(6, plotlyOutput("amount_curve"))
          )
  )
```

You will get new problems then but I think you can probably solve them by your self.